# unable to install pywebview

Tags: python, selenium, webview, pywebview

I try to install pywebview but it just gives me a long error: `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:`

in general, I'm trying to find a way to wrap a website in a GUI but that I can modify the screen size and cut areas of the webpage(hiding the search bar for example)

update :
using pip install
windows 10 env,
error message -

```
Complete output (6 lines):
    usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: setup.py --help-commands
       or: setup.py cmd --help
error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized
```

Comment: Are you using pip? Could you post the full error message? Also, what operating system are you using?

Comment: ill update the question now :)

Comment: put in question how exactly you use `pip`. And show full error message.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: all the traceback output is my files and ips... @furas

Comment: there is always something useful in full traceback. Sometimes even your files can shows that you run wrong file or use wrong path, etc.